# Uninstalled Anaconda now Powershell is Showing Error Everytime I Open It

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal, anaconda, anaconda3

[image]I uninstalled Anaconda3 following all the steps of the official documentation, but now whenever I open PowerShell or Terminal I get this prompt-

How do I remove it? It's really annoying.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots of text. Instead copy/paste it into your question!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your PowerShell [profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles) and remove that "conda.exe" line.